# How to write JSON column type to Postgres with PySpark?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Postgresql table that has a column with data type `JSONB`.

How do I insert `DataFrame` to the Postgresql table via JDBC?

If I have a UDF to convert the the `body` column to the `JSONB` Postgresql data type, what is the corresponding [pyspark.sql.types](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#module-pyspark.sql.types) should I use?

Postgresql Table with a `JSONB` column:

```
CREATE TABLE dummy (
  id bigint,
  body JSONB
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It turned out if I set `"stringtype":"unspecified"` as the properties of the JDBC, Postgres will cast automatically:

```
    properties = {
        "user": "***",
        "password": "***",
        "stringtype":"unspecified"
    }
    df.write.jdbc(url=url, table="dummy", properties=properties)
```

Comment: I tried this and I still get an error, albeit a slightly difference one (complains about type being "character" instead of "character varying").

This seems to be caused by the presence of NULL values.

Comment: I'm getting that exact issue @kappamaki - were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @sahibeast sorry, I don't remember if I was able to solve this. I no longer have access to the project where I was working on this, but I think I may have ended up writing a custom function using the "dataframe.rdd.mapPartitions" and "psycopg2" to write Spark data to PostgreSQL in order to work around this issue and also to be able to "upsert" rows.