# How to insert json string from spark into column of type jsonb in postgres

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have to insert json string from spark (Scala) into column of type JSONB in Postgres. I have to compute this string separately and then add this value as a new column to data frame. So used df.withColumn to add as below

```
df.withColumn("transaction_count", lit(transactionCount))
```

Below is the sample value for transactionCount

```
{"OFFLINE": {"CHEQUE": 5}, "ONLINE": {"CREDIT": 135, "DEBIT": 297}}
```

However am getting below error when inserting to Postgres

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "transaction_count" is of type jsonb but expression is of type character varying
```

I also tried to cast transactionCount to JsObject (using io.spray) dependency. But its throwing different error

```
ERROR - org.apache.spark.SparkRuntimeException: The feature is not supported: literal for '{"ADHOC":{"AHP":5},"ADJUSTMENT":{"ADJ":7},"ROYALTY":{"WEA":135,"WEP":297}}' of class spray.json.JsObject.
```

Any idea how to insert into JSONB column in Postgres from spark. Below is the sample code that am using to insert into Postgres table

```
-- table in postgres
CREATE TABLE jsonb_table (
  id           INTEGER,
  sample_name  VARCHAR(50),
  json_data    JSONB
);


val st = """{"OFFLINE": {"CHEQUE": 5}, "ONLINE": {"CREDIT": 135, "DEBIT": 297}}"""
val jsonData = Seq((1, "name1"), (2, "name2"))
val jsonDF = spark.createDataFrame(jsonData).toDF("id", "sample_name")
val dfWithJSONB = jsonDF.withColumn("json_data", lit(st))

val jdbcUrl = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db"

dfWithJSONB.write
      .format("jdbc")
      .option("url", jdbcUrl)
      .option("user", "postgres")
      .option("password", "password")
      .option("dbtable",  "jsonb_table")
      .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
      .mode("append")
      .save()
```

Thanks

Comment: please share ddl of your postgress table & also sample input & expected output

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46087908/how-to-write-json-column-type-to-postgres-with-pyspark)?